# how to transfer control from one non web based script to another in php and not return to first program?

Tags: php, controls

Is there a way to transfer control, similar to exec() but not return.
this is NOT from a web request, so header() won't be helpful.

I'd like to emulate something like:

```
php program1.php ; php program2.php
```

However from within the php execution.

```
instead of exec("program2.php") ; exit 
something like chain("program2.php")
```

which would exit the current script, and then re-execute the program2.php?

where the program1.php would determine which script to execute next.

I'm assuming using exec() potentially could be a memory issue if both scripts are memory hogs.

Addendum:
Looks like at present my options are:

1. using exec("....&"); exit;
2. using pcntl_fork();
3. some kind of self creating batch file

Comment: What's wrong with `require 'program2.php'; exit;`?

Comment: A batch file might be useful.

Comment: @kmoser - pcnt_fork() looks promising.  wouldn't require maintain all variables from script1 when script2 loads/executes?

Comment: @GetSet - batch wouldn't help if script1 determines which script to jump to next. I'll play with fork() and see if that helps.

Comment: It will work if script1 creates another batch file that is "called" by the starting batch file. script1 can then write anything to that 2nd batch file based on whatever conditions and logic.

Comment: @GeorgeGallen be mindful of zombie processes when using `pcntl_fork()`, be sure to set conditions up to prevent them from crashing your server.

Comment: @GeorgeGallen personally I recommend a [Message Bus](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) system to queue/dispatch and execute/consume your desired commands. It is a lot more elegant and robust, giving you more control than forking the current running process to run the desired script.

Comment: @GetSet OK - i see that. my concern is the potential security implications if someone overwrites the second batch file prior to it being executed - difficult yes - but there.

Comment: @Will B - thanks for heads up. will keep that in mind when i test out options next week. For the purpose of the application, its most like not worth time to invest in a robust solution - but something to think about for another project down the road.

Comment: Forgot about the "&" for background running. Doing exec("./somescript.php &"); exit;  would do what I'm after.  Granted, it might be unix dependent (not sure if windows has the & functionality).  Will also have to look into whether it carries the same ophaning risk as forking does. But I like that for starting.  Thanks.